# React router v4 replace param with <Link/>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My `DashBoard` component renders a shared component called `PostComments` that renders a list wrapped with `<Link/>`, When a list is click the page navigates to `Profile` component and on this component i also have the `PostCOmments`

Now, if i click one of the list on my `Profile` component the url param just stacks up Like this, http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard/5b6c5223514959110c492086/49182d98319138e31da42356

```
<Link replace to={`${match.url}/${i.comment_from._id}`}>
     <div className="comment-user-image" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${i.comment_from.photo_url})`}}>
     </div>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually replace the last part of your url because you re-use it.

```
const splitUrl = match.url.split('/'); // Split into array
splitUrl.splice(-1, 1, i.comment_from_id); // Replace the last part with the new id
return ( 
  <Link replace to={splitUrl.join('/')}> // Recreate the correct url
  // ...
```